# How can I create a wifi network around my windows 7 laptop so my windows phone can connect to it?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, windows-phone

I have a wired connection to my laptop but no wifi. I have tried creating a wifi network in the manner suggested here http://lifehacker.com/5369381/turn-your-windows-7-pc-into-a-wireless-hotspot but - thought the network appears on my other devices - it does not seem to be recognised by my nokia 620 windows phone 8 device. Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Phone does not support connecting to ad hoc networks. You can use a program like Connectify to create an infrastructure AP if your laptop wifi card supports it.

Comment: I thought this might be the case; are there any free alternatives to connectify that might work?